# Why LineBreak shown "n" in php?

Tags: php

I need help! Please, I use message form like facebook and twitter, new message slidedown effect. I used line break but shown "n" in new message. When refresh browser, Line break not shown "n". Sorry for my English used. :D

Comment: If your English is too bad, use code to explain.

Comment: I used a lot of pages, I don't know how to show code.

Comment: $fil = html_entity_decode($fil);
$fil = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($fil));

Comment: I used above code but does not work in new messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using \n to put line break you have to enclose it in "

```
"Text \n this is on new line"
```

Have in mind that for HTML output you have to use `<br />`

Comment: I think you nailed it.
Here is the doc about it : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

Try either `\r\n` or `<br/>`.

Cheers

Comment: @kjtl: Use backticks to disable HTML interpretion.

Comment: @Boldewyn Could you tell me about backticks to disable HTML interpretion? Thanks

Comment: @Begineer: If you write here at stackoverflow.com, you can put any HTML in backticks (`), and then it will be printed out literally. That has nothing to do with your question, sorry. It was meant for kjtl to improve his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're displaying messages which contain newlines (\n) and you want to display these in HTML output, keeping the newlines, then you should use [nl2br](http://www.php.net/nl2br) to convert the newlines to HTML line break (BR) tags.

Comment: I am already used nl2br but does not work in new message. When refresh page, n is hidden :D

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can print line-break with the PHP_EOL constant without use /n

example:

```
$string = "First Line".PHP_EOL."Second Line";
echo $string
```

the output is:

```
First Line
Second Line
```